# Grouping child records based on criteria

Tags: apex, visualforce, map

I have a scenario as below

Account --> contact (multiple)

Multiple contacts can be related to an account and I want to get only the contacts where there is a field called industry != a specific criteria.

eg:
How do I group all the contacts that are related to an account where the contact's industry != 'Electronics' and this needs to be displayed on a visual force page. I think I need to create a map of account, contacts_with_industry!='Electronics' and use this map in VF, but the problem is map does not accept duplicate key (account Id)

How do i get only those contacts related to the account where it does not meet a specific criteria

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Can you add to your question and include some code which you've attempted to use to solve this problem?

Comment: did the answer help you or can you provide more context to help us answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question specifically:

> How do i get only those contacts related to the account where it does not meet a specific criteria

It can be done a couple of ways depending on how you wish to work with the results. If you just need a list of Contacts with data on each Contact about their related Account:

```
List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id
                                , FirstName
                                , LastName
                                , Industry__c
                                , AccountId
                                , Account.Name                              
                            FROM Contact
                            WHERE Industry__c != 'Electronics'];
```

If you want a list of Accounts with a list of Contacts under each one you can use a subquery:

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id
                                , Name
                                , (SELECT Id
                                        , FirstName
                                        , LastName
                                        , Industry__c                                                                   
                                    FROM Contacts
                                    WHERE Industry__c != 'Electronics')
                            FROM Account
                            LIMIT 5];
```

Each account in the list will have child list identified as Contacts. The nested list can be accessed in a variety of ways.

Apex:

```
for (Account a : accounts) {
    for (Contact c : a.Contacts) {
        system.debug(c.FirstName);
    }
}
```

Similar markup in VisualForce:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="a">
    <apex:repeat value="{!a.Contacts}" var="c">
        <apex:outputText value="{!c.FirstName}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```